# What could be the definition of constructible map here:

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am studying about Mayer-Vietoris Sequence from the notes which I found on internet here: [http://math.columbia.edu/~syu/s19-eat/s19-eat-notes-mar28.pdf](http://math.columbia.edu/%7Esyu/s19-eat/s19-eat-notes-mar28.pdf) . I am taking a topology course this semester and I think my prerequisite knowledge is not sufficient so I did some self study from internet.

[image]

The above image is from the page 7 of the pdf.

> $\partial$ is given as some constructible map. But what exactly is the definition of a "constructible map"?

Please help me. I really want to understand Mayer- Vietoris condition and it would not be possible without understanding what $\partial $ can be here.

Comment: Iirc it's just some sort of group homomorphism

Comment: I think by "constructible" the author means that we can explicitly construct this function. Which is stronger than just "exists". The remark that follows explains that. Read more about snake lemma here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma

Comment: You need a complete reference, since any intro text will contain an explicit definition of this "connecting homomorphism."

Comment: I am pretty sure that in homological algebra there is no such term as constructible map. Usually in long exact sequences of (co)homology groups the connecting map $\partial$ is given by an explicit formula in terms of the diagram chase (or it can be described in terms of some canonical universal morphisms in the theory of Abelian categories). So, it seems to me that the word constructible was used there to mean that this map can be constructed by some explicit procedure (similar to what is usually meant by the word canonical).

Comment: I guess they’re saying the precise definition isn’t important. But it’s definitely explained online somewhere just look up: “exact sequence induces long exact sequence of homology”

Comment: Anyway, I completely disagree with the statement of this theorem.  It makes no sense to claim a sequence is exact without first defining *every* homomorphism.  And, the magic of homology is often intricately linked to the *precise* definition of $\partial$:  the whole reason the theory is successful is that the connecting map allows information from one dimension to pass to another.  And finally, the definition of $\partial$ is *very particular* and natural, and it can't be just any old homomorphism.

Comment: See the following for a brief explanation: https://web.northeastern.edu/suciu/MATH7221/les_homology.pdf . Can be read in conjunction with the Wikepedia article on "Snake lemma."

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I don't disagree, but it's hard to verify "the following sequence is exact" when $\partial$ is just "some" map.  I would be happier if it was phrased as "*there exists* a map $\partial$ for each $n$ such that..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a formal term. In this context I assume the author just means a map that one can give a construction of. But often the construction of $\partial$ is not important and for simple applications it suffices to know that $\partial$ exists, so the author is omitting its construction for brevity.